# Can Spring Boot achieve everything what a Spring MVC framework can?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm in a situation where I got to recommend to my team whether we should go with Spring MVC Framework or with Spring Boot framework (as this framework has reduced the implementation time to great extent). I have worked on several Spring MVC projects so I am aware what can be accomplished using Spring MVC, but I have also been working on Spring Boot since a while.

Hence I know the difference between these two great frameworks. But here the question is, does Spring Boot let us implement anything like Spring MVC provides features to implement almost anything?

I don't know what requirements we will be getting from client as well as I'm newbie to Spring Boot framework so that's the reason I doubt on this framework. In general which framework you would recommend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Boot is basically a set of configuration choices made default on top of "vanilla Spring", so in terms of feature completeness the both have the same features, meaning that the things you can do are totally the same.

Since Spring Boot favors convention over configuration, it makes sense if your application does not have any complex requirements that deviate deeply from the Spring Boot conventions (although every convention can still be overridden); for your average MVC application, then, Spring Boot provides out-of-the-box most of the configuration details you have to sort out anyway with Spring.

Being a layer on top of Spring means also that you may want not to use Boot in cases when your application has some needs that are not yet covered by Spring Boot plugins; however, these seem pretty uncommon to me.

In any case, Spring Boot is still Spring, so if you and your team are already proficient with Spring it should just be a matter of learning Spring Boot's conventions, which are inspired by how people used Spring through the years so they are quite straightforward in my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

In one word : **YES**. Spring Boot leverage all handy Spring MVC's stuffs and teribly simplifies the development. Beside that, if you want to customize what Spring Boot auto-configures it's up to you.

I also developped some apps using Spring MVC using Apache Tile and Spring Boot let me do the same configurations as in Spring MVC. Since the day I used Spring Boot I simply can not do anything without it.

It also offers other nice tools like `Actuator` and `DevTools` which are very handy for developpers.

Other nice stuff offers by Spring Boot is the ease of testing. You can test your web app starting a real server (the embedded one), etc...

Your team can take the step towards Spring Boot, they'll save lot of time.